# default eclips's android new activity crashes

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm learning my way through the android tutorials. I have a problem with the [new activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#AddToManifest) lesson. If I allow the app to call the `PlaceholderFragment` (which I don't know yet what it does) the app crashes. If I don't everything works as expected. This is the `PlaceholderFragment` section as generated by eclipse

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I compile the code using eclipse, and run it on Nexus 7 device (the latest version). The minimum android version is 2.2.3, and the current one is the latest.

Is this something I did? Something with my device? Something with my eclipse setting?

**Edit**

```
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.dungeonworlddruid:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41fcb9d0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
03-29 20:41:57.934: E/AndroidRuntime(26725):    ... 11 more
03-29 20:41:59.275: I/Process(26725): Sending signal. PID: 26725 SIG: 9
```

Comment: @please copy and paste what your LogCat says

Comment: Post the stacktrace. i don't want to post an answer by guessing and guessing wrongly

Comment: And if you are not interested in fragment you could get rid of all the codes related to the same. and this crash hash nothing to with eclipse settings

Comment: @Raghunandan I've uploaded the catlog output. I use eclipse only for this android thingy, is there anything else you wish me to upload? What I'm bothered with, is why a default code is faulty.

Comment: @LisaAnne, I've uploaded one by your request.

Comment: @Yotam i guess you are no interested in fragment. get rid of those codes. Extend `Activitiy` instead of `ActionBarActivtiy`. Then it will work fine although i pointed out why it crashes

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id
>   0x7f05003c (com.example.dungeonworlddruid:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{41fcb9d0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}

You do not have a `ViewGroup` with the id `container` in your `activity_main.xml`

Generally its `FrameLayout`. You add or replace fragment to the container.

But if you are no interested in having a Fragment get rid of all those codes related to fragment.

This update of Adt is causing a lot of confusion to developers. No setting change is required in eclipse and it has nothing to do with eclipse